# vite-plugin-sveltekit-compile - Unable to find the vite-manifest file during build

Tags: node.js, vite, sveltekit

All of a sudden the `vite build` command is giving me the following error when I try to build my svelte project. I reverted to an earlier version from git and that didn't work.

I created a new svelte kit project as well as deleted the npm global cache directories in case it was broken.

````
error during build:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<dir>\.svelte-kit/output/client/vite-manifest.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3)```

Seems like the vite-manifest file is only generated during the build phase and cleaned up afterwards.

I think something is wrong at a global level, and not able to trace this. Any pointers would be helpful.
````

Comment: Delete your `dist` and `.vite` directories. Rerun `vite build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I raised a bug on vitejs repo and they responded like

`There seems to be a race condition in sveltekit: sveltejs/kit#10268 Feel free to create a new issue if it turns out this is a bug in Vite.`

Reference:
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/14226

What works is if I run `vite build` from the command line instead of `npm run build`. For some reason, the error only comes with the `npm run build` command.